# How Can I create Contact form in ASP.NET Core with changeable From email

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core

How can I create a contact form with changeable "From" email?

I want to create a form where user can put his email and a message and send it to my email `donczyk.maciej@gmail.com` but I want a "from" email to be this email which was put in form.

My code is

```
var mail = new MailMessage("maciejka220@tlen.pl", "donczyk.maciej@gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("maciejka220@tlen.pl");
mail.Body = "Test";

using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtpClient.Port = 587;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("donczyk.maciej@gmail.com", "mojehaslo");

    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

`maciejka220@tlen.pl` is just an example email "from".

Comment: Here's Microsoft documentation on the SMTP client From property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from?view=netcore-3.1 - Unless you're getting an error message, then I'm not sure what else to suggest?

Comment: You want an html form that a user can input their email and password, then that sends you an email? Did I read this correct?